# Get coordinates of ActionEvent

Tags: java, android, motionevent

I got a little problem.
In the following sample the first TextView has to show the type of MotionEvent-it works fine. The second TextView has to show the coordinates of the MotionEvent-but it doesn't work. I don't know why but maybe its only a small error ?
Does anyone has an idea?
Thanks for your help!
Here is the Code:

```
package de.androidnewcomer.motionevent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static android.R.attr.x;
import static android.R.attr.y;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    FrameLayout Spielbereich=(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.Spielbereich);
    Spielbereich.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    TextView textView1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView textView2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    TextView textView3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    TextView textView4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    int x1,x2,y1,y2;
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            x1 = (int)event.getX();
            y1 = (int)event.getY();
            textView1.setText("Action Down");
            textView2.setText(x1,y1);
            return true;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            x2 = (int)event.getX();
            y2 = (int)event.getY();
            textView3.setText("Action Up");
            textView4.setText(x2,y2);
            return true;
        }
    } return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think u are using `setText(...)` wrong. In the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) you can See that `TextView` has the following `setText` methods:

- `final void  setText(int resid)`
  Sets the text to be displayed using a string resource identifier.
- `final void  setText(CharSequence text)`
  Sets the text to be displayed.
- `void    setText(CharSequence text, TextView.BufferType type)`
  Sets the text to be displayed and the TextView.BufferType.
- `final void  setText(int resid, TextView.BufferType type)`
  Sets the text to be displayed using a string resource identifier and the TextView.BufferType.
- `final void  setText(char[] text, int start, int len)`
  Sets the TextView to display the specified slice of the specified char array.

You are trying to use a `setText(int,int)` which is not supported.
You should do something like `textView2.setText(x1+" "+y1);`

Comment: Thanks for this fast answer. I will try it like this. But I also try ... textView.setText(x1); and it also doesnt work...

Comment: `text.setText(x1)` will set the text to be displayed using a **string resource identifier.** So it will not work as you expect.

Comment: I try textView.setText(x1+" "+y1). It was the only error - now it works fine. Thank you very mouch!